# How to get the view of a ListView item?

Tags: android, listview

I have two ListViews (A and B) with items of the same type (a class I created)

When I click on an item from A, it adds this object on B and if I click again it removes it.
Only that when an item is selected, I change its background using view.setBackgroundColor(myColor).

I want to be able to remove the item from list B (it works), but I want also to reset the background color. I can't figure out how to get the view of this item I'm removing.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you show us some of your code (the relevant part), it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: I forgot to mention I use tabs to switch between the lists. Concerning the code, there's nothing much complicated, I extended ArrayAdapters, and onClick I use view.setBackgroundColor(myColor)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no guarantee that any specific ListView item will even have a view at any given time.  If the item is currently off-screen, then it may not have a view.  Since a specific item might not have a view, it might not make any sense to try to get the item's view.

Beyond that, because of the way ListView creates and reuses views, you'll see some odd, undesirable effects if you simply modify the views directly.  As the user scrolls through the list, items that become visible will incorrectly end up with the same backgrounds as other items that have fallen outside the visible portion.

I don't know whether what follows is the best way to implement your functionality because I don't know the cost of rebuilding the list after a change.  Here's the (probably naive) way I would do this:

1. Add another boolean member to your data object, something like `isInSecondList`.
2. Override `getView()` in the Adapter.  In `getView()`, set the background to either normal or highlighted depending on the the value of the item's `isInSecondList`.
3. When an item is added or removed from the second list, update the data object to reflect the change, then call the Adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Hi, I don't dislike the solution. Only I wasn't clear enough, maybe you'll have somthing to add if I tell you I used one single TabActivity which holds the two lists.

Comment: I didn't add the boolean, instead I checked if the list contains the object. As for steps 2 and 3 I did what you suggested and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: i think answer number 3 is best way to get view in list view

Answer (score 5):

```
int position = 0;
listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
View wantedView = adapter.getView(position, null, listview);
```

Comment: YES , its good way to get position base view of list view in android thank you , I test 10 or more way but its best

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did

```
private View oldSelection;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long arg3) {
        highlightSelectdListItem(position);
}

    public void highlightSelectdListItem(int position) {
    clearPreviousSelection();
    View newsItemView = mGridVIew.getChildAt(position);
    oldSelection = newsItemView;
    newsItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
  }


public void clearPreviousSelection() {
    if (oldSelection != null) {
        oldSelection.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

}
```

Comment: its not working because of off-screen list view , for example when i touch 50th item by on item click position this code return **null**--->
`View newsItemView = mGridVIew.getChildAt(position);`

its because of that the list view calculate the position from top of viewed item in screen not in list