# View.getChildAt findViewById returns NPE

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app utilizes `RecyclerView`. Here's the xml for the content of each item in the `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvExpenses"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#009dde"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dip">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/tvGuestID" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:id="@+id/tvGuestName"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Switch
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:id="@+id/swCheckIn"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textOff="no"
            android:textOn="yes" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now I got the index of the item in my `RecyclerView` that I want to toggle it's switch, so here's how I did it:

```
indexOfGuestIdToCheckIn = listGuestID.indexOf(guestIdToCheckIn);
View view = rvGuestList.getChildAt(indexOfGuestIdToCheckIn);
Switch swCheckIn = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.swCheckIn);
swCheckIn.setChecked(true);
```

I thought the code above would toggle the switch of the selected item in my recyclerview, but instead it returns `NullPointerException` at `Switch swCheckIn = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.swCheckIn);`

Comment: Where do you call your code?

Comment: ok what value getting when calling `view.getChildCount()` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK cannot resolve method getChildCount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views are not inflated yet if they are not visible on screen As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5435999/4676276) has stated. The link also provides an interesting solution you can check.

For your case you should track your models/objects inside on the adapters getView() and decide if it should be checked or not by checking it against a list of your IDs and what values that it should have.

```
HashMap<Long, Boolean> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
// put values on hashmap

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     final <OBJECT> item = getItem(position);
     Switch swCheckIn = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.swCheckIn);
     Boolean isChecked = hashMap.get(item.getId())
     if(isChecked != null && isChecked) {
         swCheckIn.setChecked(isChecked);
     }

}
```