# How to Set Listview's Childitem Clicklistener in MainActivity Not in Adapter (In android)?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener

Hey guys This is my first question on stackoverflow.
I am searching on a topic almost for 1 month but did not find any relevant answer.

I want to set **clicklistner to the *list child items*** in the main activity.

**I know about Listview.setOnItemClickListner...   and also know how to set listview's child item clicking in own adapter.**

But i don't want this..
**I want to set listview's child item clicking in the main activity**

this is my main activity code for list item clicking...

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id) {


            final TextView tx;
            tx=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textList);



            tx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(listviewclick_Activity.this, "in=    "+String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      // clicking for textview on list   
                }
            });



            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(listviewclick_Activity.this,"out=   "+ String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // clicking for whole listitem
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

This code works fine but it has a problem that a user has to click first 
time after that all clicking will be set...

**Remember i dont want to click a childitem in adapter. i only want to click it in main activity.**
Hoping for a good answer...

Comment: You set a click listener inside a click listener, so what did you expect? You **need** to set the click event in the Adapter getView method

Comment: If i set clicklistener in adapter getview method then i will not be able to do some tasks for example if i want to refresh the list and call the json again by clicking on child item then i can't do it in Adapter getview method.

Comment: @rajatkathuriya, actually you can !, just create an interface [callback interface contains some method to implement] and pass a ref. of it to your adapter and then after clicking on what ever u want to click call that callback's method which should be implemented in MainActivity.

Comment: @rajatkathuriya also u can create an public or protected method in ur main activity to refresh the data and then you would pass `this` [of your main activity] to the adapter and onClick casts `this` to ur main activity and then used to call this method !

Answer (score 0):

I don't understands what you are doing but this part:

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(listviewclick_Activity.this, "out=   " + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // clicking for whole listitem
        }
    });
```

is wrong !, because `view` is the list view item (row) that is already clicked.

instead replace it with:

```
Toast.makeText(listviewclick_Activity.this, "out=   " +String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // clicking for whole listitem
```

Also this part:

```
tx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(listviewclick_Activity.this, "in=    "+String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      // clicking for textview on list   
                }
            });
```

will not work unless you click the listview item, so u should move it inside the adapter.

Comment: But there are many limitations in Adapter getview method. Is there any way to do it in main activity ???

Comment: If you want to assign a listener to some component in listview item (row) u will have to get this view and then find your component and finally assign the listener but this is not a good way, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5435999/5993410) so I think it is better to assign components listeners inside Adapter's `getView`

Comment: I see the answer that you have provided by the link. It's pretty good but when we are clicking on child item then it is must obvious that the view is visible. So is there any other way to do it in main activity????    Your response is precious for me...

Comment: @rajatkathuriya, If u want to click on any row, u can do this in ur main activity just like u did but don't call listener inside listener [the first correction i have provided] but if u want to click an component in some some row not the row itself, i have never seen someone do that outside adapter!